# Javascript issue: regex issue finding matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm sure it's simple and I just don't see it. I've been searching for examples and as short and simple as they are, I can't seem to find my issue.

I wish to validate a Postal Code field and use the Canadian Postal code format. I found an expression I wish to use and it looks like the following:

```
var validZIP={
   "US":"^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$",
   "UK":"^(GIR|[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]??|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z\d]??)[ ]??(\d[A-Z]{2})$",
   "CA":"^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$"
}
```

Please note the `CA` which stands for CAnada in this case.

My `onChange` function calls the following method (onchange class `checkValidPostal(this)` from the input):

```
function checkValidPostal(input)
{
    var re =  new RegExp(validZIP["CA"]);
    var value = input.value.toUpperCase();  
    if (value.match(re))
    {
        input.value = value;
        return true;    
    }
    input.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

I have checked the RegEx line using:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and it works great on that page, but for some reason I can't get it to work on mine!

Please help.

Comment: what are you passing in as input?

Comment: Why are you using `match` and not `test` ?

Comment: I was passing in values such as : m5m5m5 or M2M2M2 ... etc. I used some console.log statements to validate that the test is happening, and the values are getting through, but the test is returning false.

Comment: I tried using TEST, but for some reason I couldn't do `re.test(value)` because it would give me an error that the object `^([ABCEGH...` doesn't have a function `test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem : as you use strings instead of [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), you lack some escapements.

Besides, you probably want to use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of match.

You could fix that like this :

```
var validZIP={
   "US": /^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$/,
   "UK": /^(GIR|[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]??|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z\d]??)[ ]??(\d[A-Z]{2})$/,
   "CA": /^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/
}

function checkValidPostal(input) {
    var re =  validZIP["CA"];
    var value = input.value.toUpperCase();  
    if (re.test(value)) {
        input.value = value;
        return true;    
    }
    input.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I was going to mention the use of `RegExp#test` over `String#match` as well. You can see this working at http://codepen.io/bbuck/pen/cBkou

Answer (score 2):

Inside a string you'll need to double-escape your backslashes, else they are already escaped by the string and there are no backslashes remaining by the time the RegEx constructor gets the string.

Comment: are you saying I should change : `"CA":"^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$"` to this: `"CA":"^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\\ {0,1}(\\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\\d)$"' ?

Comment: You're right! That was the problem all along. I will be removing the quotes from the regex strings in the array. Thanks so much Bill!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting pattern instead of strings in validZIP:

```
var validZIP={
   "US":/^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$/,
   "UK":/^(GIR|[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]??|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z\d]??)[ ]??(\d[A-Z]{2})$/,
   "CA":/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/
}
```